# Why SFSymbol animation doesn't work in TabItem?

Tags: ios, swiftui

The newly introduced `symbolEffect` animation works fine in regular views, but it doesn't work when we try to use it along with `TabItem`

Is it bug on Apple's side or simple it doesn't work in `TabItem`?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selection: Int = .zero

    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            VStack {
                Label("Test Label", systemImage: "binoculars")
                    .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: selection)
            }
            .tag(0)
            .tabItem {
                Label("Search", systemImage: "binoculars")
                    .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: selection)
            }

            Text("B")
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Test", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                        .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: selection)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screen Recording symbolEffect]

Comment: Probably because of the same reason you cant resize, etc. `TabView` isn't very flexible.